# Is there a option to restrict downloading of heavy files in MS Outlook?

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-office, email-client

While using Microsoft Outlook, I get mails which are 25MB or more which keeps on downloading for long time and if there is a drop in the internet it gets downloaded again. This makes my other pending mails suffer.

Is there some sort of filter option in MS Outlook which I can set to avoid such problems. I tried by checking in webmail for such options but I didnt get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [blog post](http://www.pdxtc.com/wpblog/microsoft/limit-large-attachment-downloads-in-outlook-2007/) tells you how to do this in a few clicks, it even has a nice picture.

In summary:

- Choose Tools – Options – select the Mail Setup tab
- Click the Send/Receive rectangular button – select the group on the left, then select the Edit button.

By default, `Download complete item including attachments` is selected, but you can change the settings to `Download only headers for items larger than X`

- Pick the size you’re willing to tolerate for X, and save.